# Localizable.strings & prefix operator

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to make adding localized strings a bit easier:

```
prefix func § (string: String) -> String {
   return NSLocalizedString(string, comment: "")
}
```

Using it like this:

```
let hello = §"hello_string"
```

While this works great when manually adding these strings to Localizable.strings, they are not automatically added with "Export Localizations" anymore. Also tried the following approaches which seem to have the same issue:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56445894/14542345
2. [Localized string with argument adds line breaks and brackets around argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61932291/localized-string-with-argument-adds-line-breaks-and-brackets-around-argument)

Is there a way around this? Or is the only solution to use `NSLocalizedString("hello_string", comment: "")`?

Comment: Did you turn on "Use Compiler to extract Swift strings"?

Comment: Could not get it to work, used this approach instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56419974

Comment: Cool, thanks for reporting back. Can we close this as a duplicate of that?

Comment: Sure, thank you.